# Add 0 in middle of the string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

If i have the following string

Actual String: `11111-222`

Need to replace like by adding zero after '-'

Formatted String: `11111-0222`

I try the combination of substr, instr but its not working. Can someone please help me how i resolve the above problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Your "actual string" is nine characters long. Inserting a zero after the sixth character is not *"the middle of the string"*. So please edit your question to explain exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '-', '-0')
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution.

Comment: It is not true that 0 comes after '-'. It may be like 11111-123, 11111-234 etc.

Comment: @MohsinALvi - What do you mean? Please clarify.

Comment: This post does exactly what you asked for: `Need to replace like by adding zero after '-'`. It replaces `-` with `-0`, which is the equivalent of adding a zero after `-`.

Comment: @MohsinALvi . . . You asked a very simple question.  I provided a very simple answer.  Apparently, your question does not fully capture what you intend.  That is why sample data, desired results, and a good explanation are needed.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohsin ALvi

Do you want to [LPAD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm) the data on the right side of the hyphen so that it is 4 characters long?  If so, consider using the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) function.  Examples below:

```
select LPAD(REGEXP_SUBSTR('11111-222','\w[^-]*$'),4,0) from DUAL
```

Also, please clarify your initial post.  Thanks!